# how to bind a struct to a DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu, struct

I'm using C# in my ASP.NET application, and there are some properties that I don't want to store in the database. I would like to use a defined struct for these properties, like this:

```
public struct MedicalChartActions
    {
        public const int Open = 0;
        public const int SignOff = 1;
        public const int Review = 2;
    }
```

So I get the integer value when I use `MedicalChartActions.Open` which equals "0", but how can I bind it to a `DropDownList` control so I can display the variable name? How can I get the variable name by the value? For example, how can I return "Open" if the value equals "0"?

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: it's an asp.net web application. I updated my post. Thanks.

Comment: Well you'd definitely be using reflection for this.  Is there a reason why you have to use a struct, and not store key/values in a dictionary or something?

Comment: The struct part is irrelevant here - the fact that they're constants is much more important.

Comment: @MikeChristensen, what I want to do is reduce data server cost. it doesn't matter if I use struct or something else

Comment: @StevenZack: I'm assuming that these correspond to some enumerated table or column in the database right?

Comment: @SLaks you say use enum in this case , but what if the values contain spaces.what should we do in this case since enum cannot contain space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a structure, I would use an enumerator like SLaks suggested.

```
public enum MedicalChartActions : int
{ 
    Open = 0,
    SignOff = 1, 
    Review = 2
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
var actions = from MedicalChartActions action in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MedicalChartActions))
              select new 
              { 
                  Name = action.ToString(), 
                  Value = (int)action; 
              };

DropDownList1.DataSource = actions.ToList();
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Name";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Value";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

**EDIT**

Once you've changed the struct to an enum, you can get the name from the value like this:

```
int value = 0;
MedicalChartActions action = (MedicalChartActions)value;

string actionName = action.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks, then how to get "Open" when I have "0" known already?

Comment: @james johnson but what if we have space in values

Answer (score 0):

If it were me and you don't want to hit the database to load possible values, I'd just hard code the values into the program.

First, create the dropdown list declaratively like:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="List1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Open" Value="0" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="SignOff" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Review" Value="2" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Next, use List1.SelectedValue to get the selected value (0, 1, 2).  Note, these will be strings so if you need to work with them as numbers you'll need to cast them to integers using `Convert.ToInt32(List1.SelectedValue)`.

You can also create an enum so you don't have to hardcode a bunch of numbers in your code everywhere:

```
public enum MyEnum {Open, SignOff, Review};
```

Now you can just refer to the values as MyEnum.Open instead of 0.

Comment: The downside here is that you need to copy this DropDownList wherever the enum is used.

Comment: Yea I like your solution better.  You posted it as I was posting mine.

Comment: @MikeChristensen but how can we use spaces in enum

Comment: @Dragon - You cannot.  You'd want to bind to a dictionary for that, or just hard code the string values.

Comment: @MikeChristensen what if i use Description attribute in enum like     public enum enumtype
        {
            [Description("new cars")]
            optionone = 1,
            [Description("used cars")]
            optiontwo = 2,
            [Description("heavy bikes")]
            optionthree = 3
        }

Comment: and then get using DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])val.GetType().GetField(val.ToString()).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].Description : string.Empty;